# Contributions to the electronic properties from high-energy bands

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

In solid state physics, people sometimes call the electronic bands around the Fermi level the low-energy bands, which may include the first one or two valence/conduction bands. Discussions of electronic properties (such as thermal/optical transport, etc) are often to a great extent sufficient by invoking an effective Hamiltonian including a small number of electronic bands (e.g. <= 4), although the electrons in a kind of material may form tens of bands in the valence or conduction band manifold. It leaves people the impression that the other bands excluded by the effective Hamiltonian are less useful, if at all. Especially for the valence bands that lie further away from the Fermi energy (i.e. high-energy bands), how can we understand their contributions (either direct or indirect) to the electronic properties? In what kind of situation does the meaning of these high-energy bands become significant?

The high-energy bands are accessible from photoemission experiments along with the low-energy ones.

Comment: Because the energies involved in accessing those other bands to any great extent are not compatible with the material being in a solid state. It is kind of like asking how the 1$s$ states impact the chemistry of uranium.

Comment: I get your point. It may not be that extreme, they could be like 2-8 eV away from Fermi level, instead of core levels, which could be 10-20+ eV away.